# Python 3.6.1 - PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied shown when trying to unzip a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, io

I am facing a **PermissionError** while I am trying to extract a zip file. I have gone through a lot of discussion threads here on SO but still unable to solve my issue.

Currently I am working with Python 3.6.1 on a Windows 8 box. I have created a new directory through the following code:

```
import os,zipfile

newpath = 'C:\\home\\vivvin\\shKLSE'
#newpath = r'C:\\home\\vivvin\\shKLSE'
if not os.path.exists(newpath):
os.makedirs(newpath)
```

Next I have downloaded a zip file and saved into `newpath` directory.

Now I am trying to extract all the files (10 csv files) within the zip file to be extracted into the `newpath` directory. To achieve that I have written the following code:

```
import os,zipfile

newpath = 'C:\\home\\vivvin\\shKLSE'
path_to_zip_file = newpath
directory_to_extract_to = newpath
#zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(newpath, 'r')
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(newpath, 'w')
zip_ref.extractall(newpath)
zip_ref.close()
```

But each time I am getting an error as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/AtechM_03/PycharmProjects/Webinar/SeleniumScripts/extract.py", line 6, in <module>
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(newpath, 'w')
File "C:\Python\lib\zipfile.py", line 1082, in __init__
self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\home\\vivvin\\shKLSE'
```

I have observed the properties manually of the zip file and seems there is a Security message along with a `Unblock` button. As of now I am clueless how to `Unblock` it.[image: Unblock button]

Can anyone help me out please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pycharm dont have permission, try opening cmd after right click and then run as administrator then go to the python program folder and run your file

Comment: @Exprator Thanks for the quick look. But I am doing a lot other stuff through PyCharm with Selenium. Is there a way I can achieve the permission? Thanks

Comment: Well you can give permission while creating the folder. Check for os permission giving in python

Comment: @Exprator The permission issue is not with the directory but with the downloaded zip file. Thanks

Comment: Where is the filename of the `zip file` in your script?

Comment: @stovfl Thanks a lot for pointing that out. What if I am not sure about the exact file name? But definitely I am sure about the zip type of file.

Comment: Read about using `*.zip`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#module-glob

Comment: @stovfl Thanks for pointing to the required document. I will get back to you after going through that. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem trying to write to a file.

The fix that worked for me:

Right-click your PyCharm application and run it as administrator.

Comment: I use Vs Code and I Run it as administrator but program return permission denied

Answer (score 3):

I run into the same error when unzipping the folder "temp.zip" and only extract the file .
In my case I had a directory with a folder "temp" and a zip file called "temp.zip".

```
def unzip(path, filename): 
    with ZipFile(path, 'r') as zipobj: 
        zipobj.extract(member=filename)
```

When I run this file, I got the error message:

```
    ...
   "test.py", line 259, in unzip
        with ZipFile(path, 'r') as zipobj: 
      File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\zipfile.py", line 1090, in __init__
        self.fp = io.open(file, filemode)
    PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

The problem is, that `zipobj.extract()` needs to create a folder called temp and extract the content (temporarly). But this folder already exists. --> There I got the permission denied error.

**Solution**:

- either delete the folder "temp"
- or move the zip first to another directory and unzip it there

Answer (score 2):

I guess it's because your dictionary is on the C  drive (the windows disk ,sometimes it's forbidden to write and erase) , if you changed to the D drive,  it maybe work .

Answer (score 0):

The reason you were getting this error, is because zipfile.ZipFile() expects 3 major things from you:
first, the path if you want to specify one, then the name of the file, and the mode 'r/w'.

so going to your code again
'newpath' is a directory, which means u still need to give the filename something like

```
zipfile.ZipFile(newpath +'outputfile.zip', 'w')
```

. and here am expecting you want to archive because u were using 'w' writing mode.

and then you asked for zipfile.extractall(), which means you needed 'r' mode, and at the same time you needed to point to the folder you wanted to extract.

there is a lot of repetition in your code, which am sure you will realize when you sort this.

Answer (score 0):

## *The solution is not to run as administrator.*

You have 2 problems. The first has nothing to do with your code; this is a legitimate permission problem:

```
C:\home
```

is not a standard Windows folder. If your username is `vivvin`, your default user directory would be:

```
C:\Users\vivvin
```

Creating folders directly in `C:\` requires administrator rights. When `C:\home` was created, its owner would be set to admin by default, as would any files/folder created therein. *Creating files & directories inside it would also require admin rights. This applies recursively.* This would be the default for every created file/folder inside `C:\home` and its subdirectories until you change the owner or permissions for the folder. The process for doing this can be found on [Microsoft Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/-access-denied-or-other-errors-when-you-access-or-work-with-files-and-folders-in-windows-219af563-1953-ab4a-f17e-b0182755214e).

These issues can be avoided by simply working from your normal Windows user directory instead.

---

With permissions resolved, we hit the second problem, which is malformed code:

```
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(newpath, 'w')
```

would open a zip file to *write to*, not read from. Ignoring that problem,

```
zip_ref.extractall(newpath)
```

will attempt to write extracted contents *into* `newpath`, which is the same file you're trying to read from.

Here is the correct version of your code:

```py
import zipfile

# Use C:\Users\vivvin instead of C:\home\vivvin to avoid permission problems
newpath = 'C:\\Users\\vivvin\\shKLSE'
zippath = 'C:\\Users\\vivvin\\shKLSE.zip'
zip_ref = zipfile.ZipFile(newpath, 'r')
zip_ref.extractall(newpath)
zip_ref.close()
```

Better yet is to use a context manager. Thus, a cleaner version is:

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile

out_path = 'C:\\Users\\vivvin\\shKLSE'
zip_path = 'C:\\Users\\vivvin\\shKLSE.zip'

with ZipFile(zip_path, 'r') as f: 
    f.extractall(out_path)
```

See the [ZipFile Object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects) documentation for more details. ([Old Python 3.6 version](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/zipfile.html#zipfile-objects))