# Saving xpath attribute with for loop in the same time

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, permissionerror

Is there any way to save XPATH attribute on for loop before she ends?

```
users = set()
        for i in list:
            if i.get_attribute('href'):
                users.add(i.get_attribute('href').split("/")[2])
            else:
                continue

    print('Done')

    with open('list.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write('\n'.join(users) + "\n")
```

I tried to do it by adding directly to loop but I have an error:

```
users = set()
        for i in list:
            if i.get_attribute('href'):
                users.add(i.get_attribute('href').split("/")[2])
                    with open('list.txt', 'a') as file:
                        file.write('\n'.join(users) + "\n")
            else:
                continue
```

```
  File "C:\\", line 107, in <module>
    scrape()
  File "C:\\", line 94, in scrape
    with open('list.txt', 'a') as file:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'list.txt'
```

Comment: _before she ends_: who is she?

Comment: she is for loop, sory for my english it might be: "before it ends", in polish "loop" is feminine

Comment: Looks like a _PermissionError: [Errno 13]_. Does [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44185662/python-3-6-1-permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-shown-when-trying-t) helps you?